# Foundation5 source ordering : content vs. sidebar

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, frontend

I have a laid out structure with three columns in ZURB Foundation 5, two of which are sidebars (left & right) and the middle one is the main content area.

I've been playing around with the documentation's source ordering instructions but had some troubles.

I tried to visualise the situation so that you can understand what I want in a second.

This is the desktop view and the structure : 
[image: DESKTOP VIEw]

and this is how I want it to look like on mobile :

[image: MOBILE VIEW]

Does anyone know how am I gonna achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-6 medium-push-3 columns">Main</div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 medium-pull-6 columns">Left Sidebar</div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">Right Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

The first answer needs to use `medium-push-3` instead of `medium-push-6` and `medium-pull-6` instead of `medium-pull-3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Foundation's source ordering to alter the order at different breakpoints.

Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-6 medium-push-6 columns">Main</div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 medium-pull-3 columns">Left Sidebar</div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">Right Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Here's the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/T7rF4/)**.